# react css modules causes the snapshot tests to fail

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot, react-css-modules

The `react-css-modules` package will render a html like:

```
className="src-Comp-___style__navi-col___1-3yc6d"
```

But the hash string (`3yc6d`) will cause errors on jest snapshots:

```
<div                                                                                                                                      
  - className="src-Comp-TopcoderFooter-___style__navi-col___6dcta"                                                             
  + className="src-Comp-TopcoderFooter-___style__navi-col___3yc6d"                                                             
>
```

As you can see, the hash is changed, so snapshot test is failing.

The issue is that i cloned a repo from github, and the tests are failing because of this. (and it will probably fail when I add a pull request.)

so the hashes that are generated in my pc is different than the repo owner. (if i re-run the tests, the hash will not change.)

What's the logic behind this hash, and how can I prevent the snapshot tests to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-css-modules) library is deprecated; and [babel-plugin-react-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-css-modules) they recommend to use instead, has not been maintained for a while, and is not compatible with latest releases of Webpack's `css-loader` (which takes care about CSS name transformation on CSS side; and which determines the actual logic behind that hash, [which you can find here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/13b7458be2ef0d7a6b334e5e8149d83de6478403/src/utils.js#L181-L205)).

If you need that functionality, I recommend you to use [my fork of babel-plugin-react-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules), which I keep up-to-date, and compatible with latest `css-loader` versions :)

P.S.: And, yeah, the updates in `css-loader` from version `3.6.0` to the current `5.2.4` have altered several times the actual hash values it produces for the same class names in the same (S)CSS files.